# Unable to derive parameter information when parameter marker is a function argument

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, excel-formula

Inside Excel, under DATA > Properties

[image: DATA - Properties]

Then under definition > Command text

[image: Command text]

I have a SQL Command text to generate data table, but I've been getting this error when I use the following query string:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, (?) , 121)
```

The (?) is the parameter that I've set my cell to be `=TEXT(BE3,"mm/dd/yyyy")` which takes in `datetime` value as my `datatype` for that column in SQL Server is `datetime`

[image]

My full sql command is as of following:

```
SELECT * FROM Student 
WHERE GraduationDate 
BETWEEN
(CASE
     WHEN (GraduationDate  Is Not Null)
     THEN SELECT convert(datetime, (?) , 121)
     ELSE''
END)
AND
(CASE
     WHEN (GraduationDate  Is Not Null)
     THEN SELECT convert(datetime, (?) , 121)
     ELSE''
END)
```

Any idea what is causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is not correct.  If nothing else, subqueries need their own parentheses.

You seem to want to ignore `null` graduation dates.  Well, this logic does that:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM Student 
WHERE GraduationDate BETWEEN convert(datetime, (?), 121) AND convert(datetime, (?), 121);
```

Notes:

- I would discourage you from using `BETWEEN` with date/time values.  Aaron Bertrand has a good [explanation](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) of why.
- If you are passing parameters in, they should already be date/time values, so no conversion is necessary.
- If you want to include `NULL` values, then add `OR GraduationDate IS NULL`.

Comment: @PartTimeNerd . . . The query in your question should be generating a syntax error in SQL Server.  You are welcome to create a db<>fiddle showing that it works.